# AVAssetExportSession not exporting metadata

Tags: macos, avassetexportsession, avasset, avmetadataitem

I'm trying to use `AVAssetExportSession` to change the metadata of the file but any metadata I try to use doesn't seem to work. When I pass an empty array to `[AVAssetExportSession setMetadata:Array];` the file gets written with its unedited metadata like it's supposed to but as soon as I put an `AVMetadataItem` in the array no metadata is written to the new file. Here is the code that I used:

```
//NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[exportSession metadata]];

AVMutableMetadataItem *addingNew = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
[addingNew setKeySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes];
[addingNew setKey:AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyUserComment];
[addingNew setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is my comment"]];

NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:addingNew];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: outputFile];

[exportSession setMetadata:metaMuteArray];
[exportSession setOutputURL:fileURL];
[exportSession setOutputFileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4];
[exportSession shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse:YES]; //false doesn't work either

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch ([exportSession status])
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Export sucess");
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Export canceled");
        default:
            break;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have answered my own question. The file of which I am changing the file information is in the MP4 format so I set the filetype output to MP4 as well. This wouldn't export the metadata, changing the `setOutputFileType` to `AVFileTypeAppleM4V` did the job just fine, interestingly the output file is still and MP4, not an M4V.